# Is there a way to prevent Triss and Yennifer trapping Geralt in the Witcher 3, after you have romanced them both?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have romanced both characters, but I didn't realise this would impact the storyline and I have since decided that I wanted the so called 'Yennifer ending'. Is there a way to still get the 'Yennifer ending', even though I have romanced both women?

Comment: Play the game more than once. It's that good of a game!

Comment: True! @BryanPendleton

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but I believe the trapping is preceded by them confronting him+him saying "can't I just have you both?" presumably the other dialogue options could get other results. But I could be wrong about all of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the ending is based off of your choices you make throughout the game. Since you have made your choice, the ending will reflect what you have done obviously. You have to avoid romancing Triss throughout the game to get the Yennifer ending.

MASSIVE SPOILERS HERE (SOURCE): http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Endings

Comment: Thanks! Damn though! I wanted to get with Yennifer! Shouldn't have been a playaaaa

Comment: Don't hate on yourself too bad, it's really hard to turn down a foxy sorceress